# Subselect bad performance

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, database-performance

This is my query, it takes a long time to execute. Can I use an inner join? I am working on only one table.

```
SELECT imei,csv_data_table.time,phone_model,test_unique_id 
FROM verveba_mos.csv_data_table
WHERE time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM csv_data_table
              T1 WHERE csv_data_table.imei=T1.imei)
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you want?. @p.g

Comment: Do you have an index on `time` and/or `T1.imei`?

Comment: [_Groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS()` to do this, that doesn't necessarily means it will be faster:

`EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT imei,csv_data_table.time,phone_model,test_unique_id 
FROM verveba_mos.csv_data_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM csv_data_table s
                 WHERE  t.imei= s.imei
                   AND s.time > t.time)
```

`JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.imei,t.time,t.phone_model,t.test_unique_id 
FROM verveba_mos.csv_data_table t
JOIN(SELECT s.imei,MAX(time) as max_t
     FROM csv_data_table s
     GROUP BY s.imei) p
 ON(t.imei= p.imei and t.time = p.max_t)
```

Comment: Yes, typo, misspelled a column. @p.g Now .

Comment: i want to use inner join and reduce the time of execution, is dat possible. Please show me how.. The result should still be same as of the query i orginally gave

Comment: it worked, thank you, can you explain what we have done

Comment: Not sure I understand the question @p.g

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.imei, t1.time, t1.phone_model, t1.test_unique_id
 FROM csv_data_table t1
 JOIN (select imei, max(time) time from csv_data_table group by imei) t2
   ON (t1.imei = t2.imei and t1.time = t2.time)
```

You should also consider putting an index on `csv_data_table(imei, time)` if you don't already have one.